# xmlhttp request status 302

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to write core java script application that can test and analyse the http request. I started with below code. Firebug net tab says 302 status error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET","http://www.google.com",true);

req.onreadystatechange = statusListener;
req.send(null);
});
function statusListener(req){
    if (req.readyState == 4) 
        {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                var docx=req.responseXML;           
                console.log(docx);            
                }
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Aside of fact that `302` means `Found` and leads to redirection to other URL, you'll not get results due to cross domain policy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[3xx status codes are redirections](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

302 means "Found". Quote from w3.org:

> The requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI. Since the redirection might be altered on occasion, the client SHOULD continue to use the Request-URI for future requests.

If you want to get the page it redirects to, you have to check the URI in the response headers with the [getResponseHeader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/XMLHttpRequest#getResponseHeader%28%29) method.

You can [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) to see how to access the correct URI.

Comment: I needed the status as 200 i.e. OK

Comment: This request responds with the correct URL to request which will return 200 (the URI it redirects to).

Comment: I wanted to get request information after all with i.e. console.log(docx); which is not working

Comment: Yep, you have to check on the response's headers, not the body. You can use [getResponseHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/XMLHttpRequest#getResponseHeader()) for this.

Comment: ok. Thanks. As of now I will continue with this understanding !